# TCP Connection state hangs in SYN_SENT

Tags: windows, tcp, rtos

I have two systems A: Windows  and B: Nucleus RTOS.

B acts as server on port 50001 and A as a client to open a connection from a Windows application.

I came across the issue when the client application in A is killed and started again, the connection with  B is not formed.
The 'netstat' show the connection status in SYN_SENT state.

The server on B comes to listening mode immediately after the connection is broken and stays in listening mode.
Thus the connection state nevers comes to established and it stays in hanged state.

Is the issue in A: Windows system or in B: RTOS system ?
How this can be fixed ?

TIA

Comment: 0
down vote
 

Did you ever resolve this? I am hitting a problem that looks suspiciously similar but I cannot figure out what is causing it.

Comment: No, unfortunately was not able to get the root cause.
Though, I had some suspects,
 1. the network switch between the communicating systems was a custom build switch, it might be not routing the packets correctly.
2. the Nucleus RTOS was dropping the packets and thus the it was not able to close the broken connection.

do post your fix/findings
thanks